# Generic Method - Seeking Design Advice

Tags: c#, generics

I have a util class (C#) where I have a static method that takes a certain type of object and brings up a web service to get further data.  I would like to support other object types and to not replicate the code, i.e. add multiple similar methods, I am thinking the Generic route would be best.

For example, let's say I have:

```
public static void GetData(Building building)
{
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    var wrapper = new WrapperClass(building);

    if (building.Distance.HasValue)
    {
        structure = new Structure((decimal)building.Length.Value, (decimal)building.Height.Value);
    }

    ... // and so on ...
```

instead of creating another method(s) like so:

```
public static void GetDataForBridge(Bridge bridge)
{
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    var wrapper = new WrapperClass(bridge);

    if (bridge.Distance.HasValue)
    {
        structure = new Structure((decimal)bridge.Length.Value, (decimal)bridge.Height.Value);
    }

    // ...
```

I am not sure how to do this using Generics.  Can anyone please give me some tips or advice?

Comment: You say the web service gets further data. How do you assign them? Are they type-specific? Also, do the types share some common ancestor (with `Length` and `Height` properties)?

Comment: @svick - The service basically takes a couple parameters, e.g. Length, Height, etc., and returns other properties, e.g. Area, etc.  The service does depend on the type being fed.  The types do not have a common ancestor.

Comment: Please, be specific, ideally, show us the code. Does the “etc.” mean that the parameters and the returned value are the same for different types, or the same? *How* does the service depend on the type? Can you make a common ancestor for the types with all those properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, Bridge and Building would have to implement the same interface, say, IObjectWithHeightAndWidth.  You'd then specify this interface as a constraint on the type parameter of your generic method.

(Or, instead of a common interface, the classes could share a common base class.)

As other posters have pointed out, though, you might not need generics at all.  You only would need generics if you subsequently need to have a strongly-typed reference to the object as a `Bridge` or `Building` -- for example if you need to call another generic method in the method we're discussing.

Comment: As others have also suggested, I am going to try this.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, why not just replace `Building` in function declaration with a simpler `IHaveDistanceLengthAndHeight` interface? This way you don't need generics at all.

```
interface IHaveDistanceLengthAndHeight
{
    DistanceType Distance { get; }
    DistanceType Height   { get; }
    DistanceType Length   { get; }
}

class Building : IHaveDistanceLengthAndHeight
{
    ...
```

Comment: As others have also suggested, I am going to try this.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you should probably be using a shared interface rather than generics in this case.  Define an Interface which contains things like the Distance property and Length, Height, etc; and have your bridge and Building implement it, then define a GetData() method that takes in an instance of the shared interface.

```
public static viod GetData(IHasDimensions thing)
{
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    var wrapper = new WrapperClass(thing);

    if (thing.Distance.HasValue)
    {
        structure = new Structure((decimal)thing.Length.Value, (decimal)thing.Height.Value);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: As others have also suggested, I am going to try this.